# My browser requires Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, server

For some testing purpose I am using free hosting. I run a script to access my free hosting page. But it's saying

`This site requires JavaScript to work, please enable JavaScript in your browser or use a browser with JavaScript support`

Is there any solution to browse this site without enabling this JavaScript on my browser as I don't have JavaScript on my browser. I am using Java's browser.
[Page Link](http://smbd99.epizy.com)

Comment: Its working fine in my browser.. i think you have to update your browser....hope it work

Comment: My browser does not support JavaScript.

Comment: brother, update your browser...simple. And javascript is not a code or software that you'll install. Javascript is an environment that is supported by all modern browsers. It doesn't matter whether your browser is made up of what language. Java is a system program, while Javascript is a browser based program.

Comment: And yes you need not javascript to run your website unless intentionally/unintentionally there's some kind of javascript codes running in your webpage.

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar  I am using `URL url = new URL("urlAddress");
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`
to open the url.

Comment: ok i don't think there is a usage of javascript. Which browser you're testing on?

Comment: I am writing code with Java. Can I name it a browser? I am using Eclispe.

Answer (score 1):

You can set valid browser user agent, that supports js

1. Check beforeSend method in [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (could not work regarding to browser security reasons)
2. Use server side curl (or else) request with modified user agent